# How to sense parameters with Case

Tags: .net, vb.net, select-case

I'm trying to create a series of commands that can take parameters. To pick up each separate command I am using `Select Case` The problem with this is I can't sense the 'parameters' (the second part of the string) if I use `Case Else`. If I don't use `Case Else` then I can't handle incorrect commands and send them off to the required procedure.

For Example:

```
Private Sub AllocateType(ByVal Command As String)

    Select Case Command
        Case "Eat"
            'Call Eat procedure
        Case "Use"
            'Call Use procedure
        Case "Quit"

        Case "Pause"

        Case "Go"

        Case Else
            Errors() 'Error handling procedure
    End Select

End Sub
```

If the command was 'Brrrrr', it would call `Errors()`. Yet if the command was 'Eat Food', it would still call `Errors()` and not pass the parameters to the `Eat` procedure.

*Edit, because it now doesn't work.*
I've tried what was suggested, but I still have exactly the same problem. It seems both `Command.StartsWith` and `Command.Contains` don't work because if I try to enter 'Eat Food', it still doesn't recognise it as a case.

Example:

```
Select Case Command
    Case Command.Contains("Eat")
        Output("TESTING")
        If Len(Command) > 4 Then
            Command = Mid(Command, 4, (Len(Command) - 4))
            Interaction(Command)
        Else
            Output("Eat What?")
        End If
    Case "Eat"
        Output("Eat What?")
    Case Command.StartsWith("Use")
        If Len(Command) > 4 Then
            Command = Mid(Command, 4, (Len(Command) - 4))
            Interaction(Command)
        Else
            Output("Use What?")
        End If
    Case "Use"
        Output("Use What?")
        'Case Else
        '    Errors()
End Select
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with full examples for you :)

Comment: The edit explains it. Command.StartsWith doesn't work.

Comment: That's weird. Just tried it with If and ElseIf instead of case and it works perfectly.

Comment: I do apologise. I am new to the conventions of Stack Overflow. Anyway, All is working now.

Comment: No need to, welcome among and glad it helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True, you can keep your `Select Case` block, but since you are not checking for exact equality of `String` you should check for `Command.Contains("Eat")` or `Command.StartsWith("Eat")` depending on your goal

for insance;

```
Private Sub AllocateType(ByVal Command As String)

    Select Case True
        Case Command.StartsWith("Eat")
            'Call Eat procedure
        Case Command.StartsWith("Use")
            'Call Use procedure
        Case Command.StartsWith("Quit")
        Case Command.StartsWith("Pause")
        Case Command.StartsWith("Go")
        Case Else
            Errors() 'Error handling procedure
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an `IF` statement to preform the kind of check you want.
You have two options `StartsWith` and `Contains`.
`StartsWith` will allow you to check if your keywords are at the start of the string.

- Eat Banana = True
- Banana Eat = False

`Contains` will allow you to check if your keyword exits anywhere.

- Eat Banana = True
- Banana Eat = True

**StartsWith Example**

```
Private Sub AllocateType(ByVal Command As String)

    If Command.StartsWith("Eat") Then
        'Call Eat procedure
    Else If Command.StartsWith("Use") Then
        'Call Use procedure
    Else If Command.StartsWith("Quit") Then
        'Call Quit procedure
    Else If Command.StartsWith("Pause") Then
        'Call Pause procedure
    Else If Command.StartsWith("Go") Then
        'Call Go procedure
    Else
        Errors()
    End If

End Sub
```

**Contains Example**

```
Private Sub AllocateType(ByVal Command As String)

    If Command.Contains("Eat") Then
        'Call Eat procedure
    Else If Command.Contains("Use") Then
        'Call Use procedure
    Else If Command.Contains("Quit") Then
        'Call Quit procedure
    Else If Command.Contains("Pause") Then
        'Call Pause procedure
    Else If Command.Contains("Go") Then
        'Call Go procedure
    Else
        Errors()
    End If

End Sub
```

Also with `StartsWith` or `Contains` you can do `StringComparison` this will allow you to ignore case.

```
If Command.StartsWith("Eat", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
```

OR

```
If Command.Contains("Eat", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
```

Ignoring the case will match "EAT", "Eat", "eAt", etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can keep `Case` structure:

```
Private Sub AllocateType(ByVal Command As String)

    Select Case True
        Case Command.StartsWith("Eat")
            'Call Eat procedure
        Case Command.StartsWith("Use")
            'Call Use procedure
        Case Command.StartsWith("Quit")

        Case Command.StartsWith("Pause")

        Case Command.StartsWith("Go")

        Case Else
            Errors() 'Error handling procedure
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 i just remembered you are right, you can evaluate a value inside case statement in `VB.NET` which is not like `C#` where a constant value is expected in case statement. Been ages since i coded `VB.NET` (: